# Reformat columns/table to key/value lines in Bash

Tags: bash, awk

One of my commands in my Bash script outputs some data in table format:

```
name               requested state   instances   memory   disk   urls
test-1-API   started           1/1         2G       2G     test-1-apidomain.com
test-2-API   started           1/1         2G       2G     test-2-apidomain.com
test-3        started           1/1         3G       1G     test-3domain.com
test-4-API     started           1/1         3G       2G     test-4-apidomain.com
```

How do I get this data into rows? I.e.,

```
name=test-1-API requested=started state=1/1 instances=2G
```

etc...?

Comment: fwiw looks like |rs -T shows some promise but it doesn't like the space in "requested state"

Comment: actually rs -T only works when you have the header and one row ie | grep -A1 "requested"

Comment: so how can I keep the header and process each row directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==1 {split($0,h); next} 
                           {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=h[i]"="$i}1' file

name=test-1-API requested=started state=1/1 instances=2G memory=2G disk=test-1-apidomain.com

name=test-2-API requested=started state=1/1 instances=2G memory=2G disk=test-2-apidomain.com

name=test-3 requested=started state=1/1 instances=3G memory=1G disk=test-3domain.com

name=test-4-API requested=started state=1/1 instances=3G memory=2G disk=test-4-apidomain.com
```

Comment: whats the best way to add a new line after the urls kv?

Comment: there is already one, not?  do you mean add an empty line between the records? insert `-v ORS='\n\n'` before the script.

Comment: if I do `awk -v ORS='\n\n''NR==1 {sp` I get no program given error

Comment: add a space between the var and the script.

Comment: one more question - what if I also wanted to add a new line afer every memory kv? ie \ndisk

Comment: in the loop just do `print h[i]"="$i` and remove the `1` after.

Comment: I dont understand where to make this change? does it replace the current $i=h[i]"="$i ? where do I specify the \ndisk etc?

Comment: OK, I misunderstood.  If you replace the loop contents with what I suggested you'll get all the k-v pairs in new lines.  I don't know what "ndisk" you refer to; it doesn't exist in the sample file.

Comment: Sorry its here ```memory=1G disk=``` if I want a new line in-between memory=1G AND disk

Comment: OK, add `h[6]="\n"h[6]` after `split`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182957/discussion-between-tony-and-karakfa).

Comment: sorry, not possible.  perhaps ask another question instead.

Comment: I tired multiple locations it doesn't seem to work
awk -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==1 {split($0,h); h[6]="\n"h[6] next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=h[i]"="$i}1'